# Why Array.prototype.map(), Array.prototype.forEach(), and For-In loop give wrong result for Array.fill()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Let say I have an array created by `Array.fill()` and I want to replace the undefined value with an empty string. These are some of the methods I use:

1. With `.map()`

```js
let data = Array(5).fill(-2, 0, 1).fill(0,2,3).fill(2,4,5);
console.log(data);
data = data.map(d => d ? d : '');
console.log(data);
```

2. With `.forEach()`

```js
let data = Array(5).fill(-2, 0, 1).fill(0,2,3).fill(2,4,5);
console.log(data);
data.forEach((_,i) => {
  data[i] = data[i] ? data[i] : ''; 
});
console.log(data);
```

3. With `for ... in`.

```js
let data = Array(5).fill(-2, 0, 1).fill(0,2,3).fill(2,4,5);
console.log(data);
for(let i in data) {
  data[i] = data[i] ? data[i] : '';
}
console.log(data);
```

My expectation is to print something like this: `[-2, "", 0, "", 2]`. All three methods give same result but are not correct. Why did it happen? Did I miss something?

*Note: The purpose of this question is to replace undefined values with empty strings, not just to know why the below methods didn't work. So this question shouldn't be duplicated*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an array with `Array(5)`, it is a sparse array. This means all elements are `<empty>`. When you use `map/forEach/for in`, these functions only iterate over non-empty elements. This is why empty strings are not being filled in.

To fill it with empty strings first, do:

```js
let data = Array(5).fill('').fill(-2, 0, 1).fill(0,2,3).fill(2,4,5);
console.log(data);
```

To fill in the empty elements afterwards, do:

```js
let data = Array(5).fill(-2, 0, 1).fill(0,2,3).fill(2,4,5);
console.log(data);
data = Array.from(data, e => e??'');
console.log(data);
```

Note that StackOverflow's console function prints `undefined` instead of `<empty>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = Array(5).fill(-2, 0, 1).fill(0,2,3).fill(2,4,5);
console.log(data);
for (let i = 0; i<data.length;i++) {
    if (data[i] === undefined)
  data[i] = "";
}
console.log(data);
```

This code should work. I tried out the for-Each and it seems like to skip all indexes that are undefined. That makes sense since i is in your case also undefined.

This version iterates through every index, since i is always incremented after every iteration. Then it's easy to check if the current index has the value of undefined.